# how to boot from uImage on board imx50evk

Tags: arm, embedded-linux

I need to boot from kernel image uImage which already flashed onto sdcard using dd command of linux.
from u-boot prompt
u-boot>....

Comment: You need to copy the uImage file into main memory in order to boot the kernel using the `bootm` command.  Is there a filesystem on the SDcard, or a partition at a fixed address?  BTW you also need to have the `bootargs` environment variable setup with the "kernel command line".  And presumably the version of U-Boot is compiled for your board and will generate an appropriate *ATAG* list for the kernel.

Comment: bootm receives the address. but how can i get the address kernel image which is already flashed onto sdcard at a seek location of 2048. To flash kernel dd command is sudo dd if=uImage of=/dev/sdb bs=512 seek=2048 && sync && sync

Comment: Hi @ASB, you should read the uImage from your SD card to ram and boot from ram. we used to boot with uImage store in SD card and the SD card is formatted in VFAT file system (uboot have fatload command to read the image).

Comment: Thank you dien, ya got to know how to load kernel image but now its hang out at starting kernel... message and to get uboot prompt back i need to power off the board and on it again....

Answer (score 0):

To load the kernel from the SDcard, you probably need to do something like:

```
> mmc dev 1
> mmc read ${loadaddr} 0x800 0x2000
> bootm
```

Comment: what is 0x800 and 0x2000??? is this same for all board or do i need to change or scale it with my loadaddress....